# LibreOffice Calc - attach Javascript macro to group box button event

Tags: event-handling, controls, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

On my Mint Box 3 (OS is Mint 21) I'm using LibreOffice Calc version 7.3.7.2, I have created a Group Box containing 3 option buttons (mutually exclusive radio buttons).  I have been trying to figure out how to associate the call to the macro when a button is pushed.

I have created a macro folder under "My Macros" and a dummy Javascript macro in that folder (***Tools > Macros > Organize Macros > Javascript > ...***), and now I'm trying to figure out how to have it called on an event related to the Group Box and/or buttons in the group.

I set design mode on the form, right-click and open "*Form Properties*" dialog, selecting "*Events*" tab.  I see a list of events, but none that relates to a button selection, or button push event.  They all seem to be related to Document events.  If I open "*Control Properties*", there is no event tab.

I've spent literally days trying how to do this in Calc.  I've written a lot of code that manipulates a Calc spreadsheet through a Python program that connects through the socket (starting LibreOffice calc with:

***"soffice --calc --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"***

and have had no trouble manipulating cell contents through that program.

If anyone can point me towards some documentation or tutorial that CLEARLY elucidates the workflow to assign code to events on Group Box controls, or tell me where I need to look in the Calc menus and taskbars, I'd be grateful.

Maybe I should abandon Javascript and use Python?

Is there an approach to event scripting other than using the "Macro" workflow?

Thanks.

Comment: *on an event related to the Group Box* - wrong way. Look at the "Item Status changed" event of each of the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

SO - my confusion was related to finding the tool that associated a macro function with an actual form or control event.  I was looking in the wrong place.  I was looking in the "Form Properties" tool, which has an "Events" tab, but none of those events there actually relate to control events, like buttonPush, rollOver, etc.

The stuff you really want to use is accessed in the "Form Navigator" tool.  It took me three days to find anything that even mentioned this tool (I should have looked into this tool when I first noticed it some time ago - my bad).

For my purpose, a group control with three buttons, this dialog displays a tree with 4 items under Form, the group control and three buttons.  They all have the same name but the group control has a distinctive icon.  Thats the one you want to select, right-click it to get a fly-out menu, then select Properties.  This opens a dialog with an Events tab, that actually lists the events you want to handle.